# Graphics and applets

Tags: java, swing, graphics, layout-manager, japplet

I am currently working on an assignment and need to create basic controls (buttons) for the Mandelbrot set that will operate as a `JApplet`. The graphics is initialised in the `init()` method and a method which draws the Mandelbrot is called in `start()`. The problem is, I have searched high and low and cannot figure out how to add a GUI to my applet because

1. I don't explicitly add the mandelbrot to a JPanel , and..
2. I have no room left it seems to add a GUI because the Mandelbrot takes up the entire `JFrame`.

I had one idea which was to set the size of the `JFrame`, set the size of the Mandelbrot graphic to only be say 4/5 of the whole frame, and add buttons to the remaining portion?

Does that sound like a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

> Does that sound like a good solution?

No.  The panel in which the Mandelbrot is drawn should return a sensible preferred size.  Add the rendering panel and the buttons to a layout or groups of layouts using layout padding, borders and button margins for white space.

But I am a little confused by the reference to [japplet](/questions/tagged/japplet) tag yet the body of the question mentions both `JApplet` and (twice) `JFrame`.

- An applet has to make do with whatever size it is provided by the HTML (or JS, in the case of the deployment toolkit script) that launches it.
- A frame can call [`pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack--) on a properly laid out UI and expect to be the smallest size needed to display the components.

### General tips

1. Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).
2. For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS allows the user to launch a `JFrame` from a link in a web page.
3. Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556)<sup>1</sup>, along with layout padding & borders for [white space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556)<sup>2</sup>.

   1. [image]
   2. [image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you say "the panel in which the mandelbrot is drawn" I dont know how to add it to a panel, its drawn for me without me specifying a panel. Thats why I cannot split up the space as shown in your two pics.

Comment: *"its drawn for me without me specifying a panel"*  Do you have ***any*** idea what you are doing, or are you attempting 'coding by magic' (which doesn't work BTW)?

Comment: What I mean is, when you code an application you create frames, panels explicitly , with an applet , a frame is made behind the scenes and the graphic gets placed in it. I do not know how to use layout managers with an applet . Could somebody please give me a template or rough idea of how to have say two panels, one for the graphic, one for buttons. Thanks alot .

Comment: *"I do not know how to use layout managers with an applet"* Do you know how to use layout managers with a panel?  If so, add a panel to the applet in the `init()` method and take it from there (add other things to the main panel).

Comment: I can use layout managers and panels, and adding components with a panel , the trouble i have is that graphics / image isnt a component so I cant add it like i have been doing with other projects.

Comment: I havent been programming for that long and so i'm open to any criticisms about my lack of knowledge. Would you like me to post my code ?

Comment: For more help, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).